# MYSQL Using a replace function to replace a part of a statement with a variable

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out how to change DueDays by increasing 15 days for terms whose current DueDays is larger than 30 (I figured out that part). Then I need to change the details value to the same value as the Duedays is changed. For example, if DueDays of a term is changed from 30 to 45, then 'Net due 30 days' should change to 'Net due 45 days'.

```
ID  Details                DueDays
1   Net due 10 days          10  
2   Net due 20 days          20
3   Net due 30 days          30
4   Net due 60 days          60
5   Net due 90 days          90
```

So far this is what I came up with:

```
Update Terms
SET DueDays = DueDays + 15 AND SET Replace ( Details, '' ,
WHERE DueDays > 30;
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Very strange requirement, storing the string along with the data.  But here is one method:

```
UPDATE Terms
    SET DueDays = DueDays + 15,
        Details = REPLACE('Net due XX days', 'XX', DueDays + 15)
    WHERE DueDays > 90;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work as well

```
 Update terms
 Set Duedays = Duedays + 15,
 Details=replace(details,Duedays,Duedays+15)
 Where duedays > 90;
```